# Insert record into custom log table

Tags: talend

I have a task to insert error messages into custom log table if something wrong happens - invalid credentials, source data in incorrect format. According to this I have questions:

- how to catch error messages from components
- how to insert message into specific table in DB

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**First part** - 
to catch error messages in Talend we have few components that needs to be used such as - `tDie, tLogCatcher`. To explain briefly - for your job you have encountered some error at any of your component what needs to be done is you connect that component to `tDie` through "`On ComponentError`" or "`On SubJobError`" else "`RunIf`" could also be used if you want to specify some condition upon which the job should error out. Now, in ``` tLogCatcher`` enable the option to " ```Catch tDie`" so that all the errors are catch-ed here with relevant log details. You could also select the options to "`Catch Java Exception`".

**Second part** -
Now connect `tLogCatcher` to your dboutput component (ex: `tMSSqlOutput`, `tOracleOutput` etc...) and in there under "Basic settings" you have the option to choose/mention the `Table` where you want the records from `tLogCatcher` to be written.

Comment: And i case you have tLogCatcher outputing to a custom table, let's say, SF output, and you have an error on that component, how do you catch that error? Because I forced that error now and it catches tDies  and all but it's not printing them ...